# How to create Header and footer using Axlsx Gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, axlsx

I am trying to create the header and footer with the below code in the rails. But it is not creating the header and footer in the Excel file. Where I did wrong?

```
     xlsx_package = Axlsx::Package.new
        wb = xlsx_package.workbook
        header_footer = {:different_first => false, odd_header:'&C&14 &B&UHeader Text', odd_footer:'&L&11&BPage &P &C&11Footer Text &R&11&ILast updated:&D'}
        wb.add_worksheet(name: "header footer", :header_footer => header_footer) do |sheet|
             sheet.add_row ["First Column", "Second", "Third"]
             sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
       end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add a row & apply style properties to this row.
In below code, I have changed the background color to gray & text is made bold for header. Hope this helps!!

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook

head_style = wb.styles.add_style bg_color: "DDDDDD",  b: true

wb.add_worksheet(name: "Sheet 1") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row %w(Name Age)
  sheet.row_style 0, head_style

  sheet.add_row ['Tom',20]
  sheet.add_row ['Pete',22]

end
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs [here](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb)

```rb
header_footer = {:different_first => false, :odd_header => '&L&F : &A&R&D &T', :odd_footer => '&C&Pof&N'}
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "header footer", :header_footer => header_footer) do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["this sheet has a header and a footer"]
end
```